# Create Lock Screen Notification Like Apple's Alarm App?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, alarm, lockscreen

currently when my application is on lock screen, I just have a basic UILocalNotification pop up that opens the app when pressed and so on. However, I'd really like to make that better looking and I was wondering how Apple's Alarm Application has it's own unique notification on the lock screen? Does this also deal with manipulating notifications? Please, any help would be greatly appreciated...I've been searching for weeks :( [alarm app lock screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3hWJ.jpg)

Comment: You cannot copy the lock screen notification like the Apple Alarm App. You cannot customize local notifications in any way. Apple is the only one who can do that.

Comment: @DBoyer but i've seen whatsApp do this for their whatsApp call feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for now it is not possible to create a custom type notification like Apple Alarm Clock. There is no trace of it in `UIKit` framework docs. All we have is basic `UIAlertController` and `UILocalNotification` classes.

Comment: Ok, actually I didn't know about UIAlertControllers...do those, like UILocalNotifications, also pop up on the lock screen?

Comment: @sheavictoria Well it does pop up on the lock screen, but it's a bit different thing. That's how it looks like [link](http://nshipster.s3.amazonaws.com/uialertcontroller-alert-one-two-three-cancel.png)